# Is it possible to mount two different external nfs filesystems into 2 directories with the same radix (overlapping)?

Tags: filesystems, rhel, mount, nfs

I'd like to know if it is possible to mount two different external filesystems via nfs into two directories that overlap.

Do the overlaping directories cause any issues?

```
/usr/proj/projectA
/usr/proj/projectA/logs
/usr/proj/projectA/data
```

As an example (`/etc/fstab`):

```
192.168.11.111:/vol/DISK1/project-A-bin /usr/proj/projectA nfs
192.168.11.111:/vol/DISK1/project-A-logs /usr/proj/projectA/logs nfs
192.168.11.111:/vol/DISK1/project-A-data /usr/proj/projectA/data nfs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this snippet it sounds like the answer would be no you cannot do this and still see the files from the initial mount.

*Excerpt*

> NFS filesystems appear to be "normal" filesystems on the client, which
>   means that they can be mounted on any directory on the client. It's
>   possible to mount an NFS filesystem over all or part of another
>   filesystem, since the directories used as mount points appear the same
>   no matter where they actually reside. When you mount a filesystem on
>   top of another one, you obscure whatever is "under" the mount point.
>   NFS clients see the most recent view of the filesystem. These
>   potentially confusing issues will be the foundation for the discussion
>   of NFS naming schemes later in this chapter.

That being said I believe you'd be able to mount `logs` and `data` on top of `projectA`, and only those directories would be obscured, assuming there are `logs` and `data` directories within `projectA`.

#### Example

Here's a contrived example where I'm mounting 2 NFS shares:

- mulder:/export/raid1/proj
- mulder:/export/raid1/packages

Within the same mount point.

```
$ mount | grep /mnt
mulder:/export/raid1/proj on /mnt/test1 type nfs (rw,addr=192.168.1.1)
mulder:/export/raid1/packages on /mnt/test1/adir type nfs (rw,addr=192.168.1.1)
```

**NOTE:** The system, mulder, is the NFS server with the shares.

#### References

- [6.3. Mounting filesystems - O'Reilly Managing NFS and NIS](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/nfs/ch06_03.htm)

Comment: In my case the project-A external disk directory does not have logs or data subdir, so if I understood it correctly it won't be a problem ti mount the three external file system, as specified.

Comment: @MarioStefanutti - correct. I just confirmed that you can mount NFS mounts within other NFS mounts in the manner that you're asking about. It works as I've described.